# Difference between theme_rtl and theme?

Tags: html, right-to-left

How are you
I have just purchased HTML theme.
And there was 2 very similar directory, theme_rtl and theme.
So what does rtl mean?
And what should I used for my web site?
I compared theme with bcompare tool, and there was no difference in structure but pages in theme_rtl are using rtl for css and so on.

```
<html lang="en" dir="rtl">
...
<link href="assets/base/css/plugins-rtl.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
...
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: RTL = [Right to left](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left). So unless you're working in an RTL language, use the standard `theme`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RTL mean is "Right to Left"

Generally use for below languages

- Arabic
- Aramaic
- Azeri
- Dhivehi/Maldivian
- Hebrew
- Kurdish (Sorani)
- Persian/Farsi
- Urdu